# Swagger ReaderListener is never picked up during scanning

Tags: java, swagger

I implemented a `ReaderListener` in the same package as my resoure classes for Swagger. However, when the Swagger files are generated, this class is never used. I tried adding `swagger.setBasePath("/empty");` to `afterScan()` just to see if it was being called at all, to check if it changed the base path, but it didn't. Any idea on what I need to do to make sure this class is picked up in Swagger's scanning process? BTW, I am building the project with Maven and installing the generated RPMs if that makes a difference.

```
@io.swagger.annotations.SwaggerDefinition
public class SwaggerDefinition implements ReaderListener {
    @Override
    public void beforeScan(Reader reader, Scanner scanner) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterScan(Reader reader, Scanner scanner) {
        final Model model = new ModelImpl()
            .name("EntryContainer")
            .type("Object")
            .required("entry")
            .property("entry", new ObjectProperty());
        model.setReference("#/definitions/entry");
        final Model model1 = new ModelImpl()
            .name("Entry")
            .type("Object")
            .property("first_name", new StringProperty())
            .property("last_name", new StringProperty())
            .required("first_name")
            .required("last_name");
        Map<String, Model> defs = new HashMap<>();
        definitions.put("EntryContainer", model);
        definitions.put("Entry", model1);
        swagger.setDefinitions(definitions);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm having a similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

Even though this is a old question I thought of posting what worked for me.

Here is my ReaderListener implemention.

```
import io.swagger.annotations.SwaggerDefinition;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.Reader;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.ReaderListener;
import io.swagger.models.Swagger;

@SwaggerDefinition
public class SwaggerBasePathModifier implements ReaderListener {
    @Override
    public void beforeScan(Reader reader, Swagger swagger) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterScan(Reader reader, Swagger swagger) {
        // This is the purpose of my ReaderListener
        // Yours can be different
        swagger.setBasePath("/web-context/rest"); //<--set new base path
    }
}
```

In my case SwaggerBasePathModifier class was not getting scanned by Swagger. To fix this I had to add this explicitly as one of the class to be scanned when my rest application initialized. See comments in the code.

```
classes.add(SwaggerBasePathModifier.class);
```

And here is the full class

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class MyRESTApp extends Application {
    public MyRESTApp() {
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        // api end points
        classes.add(MyAPIResource.class);
        // swagger related
        classes.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
        classes.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);
        classes.add(SwaggerBasePathModifier.class);//<-- This does the trick

        return classes;
    }
}
```

This helped me to fix this.Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a code-only answer. It is expected that you also explain the answer.

Comment: @Sneha. I had comments in my code for the explanation but now I have added description to my post. Hope it helps you to understand the fix and resolves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is a Spring Bean which I annotated with @Component.  Make sure this class is being loaded up by Spring or whatever container you may be using.